# Core Data does not react on changed predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is a strange issue.

In my view controller `SpieleOrtTVC` I am going to present a subset of the objects of the entity `Spiel`. Every time the view controller is called a different subset should be displayed based on the users's selection within the presenting view controller.

This works just well for each first time the view controller is called. Depending on the user's selection, fetch creteria is handed over to the new view controller and actually arrives there correctly, as the NSLogs prove. The result and data displayed is as expeted.

But when the view controller is called a second or third time, then, too, the correct fetch criteria is handed to the view controller but aparenty the fetch result corresponds to the fetch that was performed earlier.

This is the code. SpieleOrtTVC is called out of a map callout. The selected object's name, which happens to be in the annotation's title, is handed over to the newly instanciated SpieleOrtTVC.

The calling view controller with a map:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)pin calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    SpieleOrtTVC *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:STORYBOARD_ID_SPIELE_ORT];

    MKPointAnnotation *theAnnotation = (MKPointAnnotation *) pin.annotation;

    NSLog(@"the Annotation %@",theAnnotation.title);

    detailViewController.ortName = theAnnotation.title;
    detailViewController.stadionName = theAnnotation.subtitle;

    [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

SpieleOrteTVC.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ortName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stadionName;
```

(Just a property, no getters or setters etc, auto-synthesized)

This is the piece of code that I doubt of SpieleOrteTVC.m:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (! _managedObjectContext) {
        _managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[self entityName] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[self sortDescriptorString] ascending:[self sortAscending]];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[self predicate]];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    NSLog(@"request: %@", fetchRequest);
    for (NSManagedObject *mo in [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        NSLog(@"fetched: %@", [mo valueForKey:ATTRIB_ANSTOSS]);
    }


- (NSString *) entityName {

    return ENTITY_SPIEL;
}

- (NSString *) sortDescriptorString{

    return ATTRIB_ANSTOSS;
}

- (NSPredicate *) predicate {

    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(spielOrt.name == %@)", self.ortName];
}

- (BOOL) sortAscending {
    return YES;
}
```

Output of the first-time call:

```
2014-05-11 13:49:16.209 myApp[2745:60b] the Annotation Porto Alegre
2014-05-11 13:49:21.937 myApp[2745:60b] request: <NSFetchRequest: 0x18c0c960> (entity: Spiel; predicate: (spielOrt.name == "Porto Alegre"); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(anstoss, ascending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 20; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
2014-05-11 13:49:21.955 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-15 19:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:49:21.957 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-18 16:00:52 +0000
2014-05-11 13:49:21.959 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-22 19:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:49:21.960 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-25 16:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:49:21.962 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-30 20:00:04 +0000
```

And this is the next call's result, with a different user selection:

```
2014-05-11 13:50:25.654 myApp[2745:60b] the Annotation Fortaleza
2014-05-11 13:50:25.675 myApp[2745:60b] request: <NSFetchRequest: 0x18c6c0e0> (entity: Spiel; predicate: (spielOrt.name == "Fortaleza"); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(anstoss, ascending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 20; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
2014-05-11 13:50:25.681 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-15 19:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:50:25.683 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-18 16:00:52 +0000
2014-05-11 13:50:25.684 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-22 19:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:50:25.686 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-25 16:00:51 +0000
2014-05-11 13:50:25.687 myApp[2745:60b] fetched: 2014-06-30 20:00:04 +0000
```

It shows clearly that the different selection criteria is taken correctly from the user's interaction and handed down to the new view controller. Especially the fetch request gets its predicate set accordingly but the results are the same in both cases. 
(the timestamp used for the sample here are unique for all objects)

What is wrong here?

I am happy to share more code. Just tell me what you think is relevant for the question.

If that is of importance: iOS 7.1.1, running on the device (iPhone 4, 4S, 5, iPad mini - all the same), Xcode 5.1.1

(I do have a workaround handy, but out of curiosity I'd like to know what the problem is.)

Comment: It could be related to the cache. Try `cacheName:nil` in the creation of the fetched results controller.

Comment: @MartinR, good idea. In the meantime I observe another effect. I have another view controller that shows the superset of all of these entity's objects. When I go ther, everything is fine so far. And the first subset view (the one related to the question above) works fine and all subsequent calls are as described above. When I use the view controller with a subset first, then the one showing the superset shows the same subset only.

Comment: Yes, with out a cache name given it seems to work. Thanks for the hint. Yould you consider this as an error in core data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `NSFetchedResultsController` reference:

> **Important:** If you are using a cache, you must call
>   `deleteCacheWithName:` before changing any of the fetch request, its
>   predicate, or its sort descriptors. You must not reuse the same
>   fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the
>   cacheName to `nil`.

So the problem in your case is that the FRC re-uses a cache that was created for a 
different predicate. Either don't use a cache (`cacheName:nil`) or delete the
cache before the new FRC is created. In your situation, a cache probably does not make
much sense.

Comment: That is right. Well, I was not using the SAME NSFetchedResultsController. For each different request it was newly instanciated along with its owning view controller. As well as this other view controller instanciates its own instance of NSFetchedResultsController. All of them, however, share the same cache.  And right, if I really need a new cache for each individual request, caching at all is kinda senseless.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: The documentation is not very clear. I think that from the "The Cache" paragraph in the FRC documentation one can conclude that it applies to new FRC instances as well. Otherwise you would not need a cache at all.

Comment: Right. But what is the sense in a cache in general, that has to be discarded every time when a new request may relate to the same entity (that is what cashes are made for, where their performance gains come from) but with different fetch criteria (predicates)? Those caches can never be shared cross classes or even objects because just because one object cannot know what another object ever did with this cache. Kinda courious.